# getting model value in controller when in ng repeat

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I have written code like below,

```
<div ng-repeat="rnewobj in rnewobjs">
    <select   name="abc" 
    ng-model="rnewobj.objkey.value" 
    ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in session_dd"
    ng-change="valuechanged()" required>
    </select>
```

How do i get the model value on change. I want to change model value from controller. How do i do this?

Comment: why don't you pass rnewobj to valuechange()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of your requirements, setting the value and printing it when it's changed (I just used a button, but you could do whatever):

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/19572/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="rnewobj in rnewobjs">
    <select
        name="abc"
        ng-model="rnewobj.objkey.value"
        ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in session_dd"
        ng-change="valuechanged(rnewobj)" required>
    </select>
    <button type="button" ng-click="reset(rnewobj)">Reset to item 1</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.session_dd = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "item1"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "item2"
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "item3"
}];

$scope.rnewobjs = [{
    objkey: {
        value: 1
    }
}, {
    objkey: {
        value: 2
    }
}, {
    objkey: {
        value: 3
    }
}];

// print the value when changed
$scope.valuechanged = function (item) {
    console.log(item.objkey.value);
};

// set the value
$scope.reset = function (item) {
    item.objkey.value = 1; // reset to 1
};
```

Comment: @ David Spence - Sorry for my mistake. This is inside a ng-repeat.

Comment: @Hacker does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement watcher function.

```
$scope.$watch('rnewobj.objkey.value', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

The value is stored in data variable.

Comment: You don't need to watch anything! That's the point of ng-change

Comment: But if he can't make it work, watcher is a simple solution and it does the same thing.

Comment: But it's anti pattern. We are agree a $watch won't make your code awful but try to avoid it every time you can.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scope` variables with the same name. It relies on Angular's two-way data-binding.
Suppossing you want to edit object index 2 on your array :

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
  var index = 2;
  $scope.rnewobjs[index].objkey.value = 'YourValue';
});
```

The value will be changed automatically on your view.

Comment: @Blackus - This object does not directly exist. It is inside a ng-repeat

Comment: You can access your object on `rnewobjs` array from controller and edit it. It will be broadcast to your view. I edited my answer consequently.

Comment: Or better (but a bit harder) yet, write a directive for it and use isolated scopes. That's how you "beautify" an angularJS app in my humble opinion.